# Scroll Up to the previous div when scrolling back to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slick.js

I am trying to scroll back up to previous section when scrolling back to top. I have the solution for scrolling continuously after last slider. But now i am not able to find for the opposite when scrolling back to top.(continuously scrolling top after fist slider) I have attached the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pavankumar_Kori/pw3svdnr/2/) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/pavankumar_kori/full/jOPbBLY) snippets for the reference

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.customer-logos').slick({
    vertical: true,
    infinite: false,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true });

});

const slider = $(".customer-logos");


slider.on('wheel', function (e) {

  var slideCount = $(this)[0].slick["slideCount"];
  var currentIndex = $(this).slick("slickCurrentSlide");
  var totalSildeToShow = $(this)[0].slick.options["slidesToShow"];

  if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  } else {
    if (slideCount - totalSildeToShow === currentIndex)
    return;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  }
});
```

```css
h2{
  text-align:center;
  padding: 20px;
}
/* Slider */

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
}
.slick-dots {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 37% !important;
    display: grid !important;
    width: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    top: 15%;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.7.1/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.7.1/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<section style="height: 100vh;background: #f436e3"></section>
<h2>Our Partners</h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed gravida, metus sit amet ornare pretium, sem velit facilisis arcu, id laoreet nibh augue ac justo. Duis pellentesque, elit id semper gravida, tellus ante porttitor nisl, et molestie nisi elit eu libero. Suspendisse ornare tincidunt tellus, vitae fermentum enim suscipit vitae. Proin et nisl sed neque commodo euismod aliquet consequat lectus. Integer vitae quam rhoncus, blandit enim ut, mollis justo. Donec pulvinar ex in facilisis venenatis. Ut ullamcorper eros sit amet leo dictum elementum eget sed urna.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="customer-logos slider">
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<section style="height: 100vh;background: #f436e3"></section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168861/take-user-back-to-where-they-scrolled-to-on-previous-page-when-clicking-browser

Comment: No not that question. I want to scroll back to previous section. When i scroll top when i am in first slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.7.1/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.7.1/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<section style="height: 100vh;background: #f436e3"></section>
<h2>Our Partners</h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed gravida, metus sit amet ornare pretium, sem velit facilisis arcu, id laoreet nibh augue ac justo. Duis pellentesque, elit id semper gravida, tellus ante porttitor nisl, et molestie nisi elit eu libero. Suspendisse ornare tincidunt tellus, vitae fermentum enim suscipit vitae. Proin et nisl sed neque commodo euismod aliquet consequat lectus. Integer vitae quam rhoncus, blandit enim ut, mollis justo. Donec pulvinar ex in facilisis venenatis. Ut ullamcorper eros sit amet leo dictum elementum eget sed urna.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="customer-logos slider">
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<section style="height: 100vh;background: #f436e3"></section>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    const slider = $('.customer-logos');
    
    function onSliderAfterChange(event, slick, currentSlide) {
      $(event.target).data('current-slide', currentSlide);
    }
    
    function onSliderWheel(e) {
      var deltaY = e.originalEvent.deltaY,
        $currentSlider = $(e.currentTarget),
        currentSlickIndex = $currentSlider.data('current-slide') || 0;
      
      if (
        // check when you scroll up
        (deltaY < 0 && currentSlickIndex == 0) ||
        // check when you scroll down
        (deltaY > 0 && currentSlickIndex == $currentSlider.data('slider-length') - 1)
      ) {
        return;
      }
  
      e.preventDefault();
  
      if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
        $currentSlider.slick('slickPrev');
      } else {
        $currentSlider.slick('slickNext');
      }
    }
    
    slider.each(function(index, element) {
      var $element = $(element);
      // set the length of children in each loop
      // but the better way for performance is to set this data attribute on the div.slider in the markup
      $element.data('slider-length', $element.children().length);
    })
    .slick({
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      arrows: false
    })
    .on('afterChange', onSliderAfterChange)
    .on('wheel', onSliderWheel);
  
  });
```

```css
h2{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  /* Slider */
  
  .slick-slide {
      margin: 0px 20px;
  }
  
  .slick-slide img {
      width:500px;
      height:250px;
  }
  .slick-dots {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 37% !important;
      display: grid !important;
      width: 0 !important;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
      top: 15%;
      right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.7.1/slick/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/slick-carousel@1.7.1/slick/slick-theme.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<section style="height: 100vh;background: #f436e3"></section>
<h2>Our Partners</h2>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed gravida, metus sit amet ornare pretium, sem velit facilisis arcu, id laoreet nibh augue ac justo. Duis pellentesque, elit id semper gravida, tellus ante porttitor nisl, et molestie nisi elit eu libero. Suspendisse ornare tincidunt tellus, vitae fermentum enim suscipit vitae. Proin et nisl sed neque commodo euismod aliquet consequat lectus. Integer vitae quam rhoncus, blandit enim ut, mollis justo. Donec pulvinar ex in facilisis venenatis. Ut ullamcorper eros sit amet leo dictum elementum eget sed urna.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="customer-logos slider">
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/luxury-letter-e-logo-design_1017-8903.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/3d-box-logo_1103-876.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-tech-logo_1103-822.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/colors-curl-logo-template_23-2147536125.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-cross-logo_23-2147536124.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/football-logo-background_1195-244.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/background-of-spots-halftone_1035-3847.jpg"></div>
<div class="slide"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/retro-label-on-rustic-background_82147503374.jpg"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<section style="height: 100vh;background: #f436e3"></section>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).